# How to you convert a Latin word, such as voluntas, into a name, specifically a surname?

Tags: classical-latin, declension, example-request, names, case

I've been wondering how to properly convert Latin words into names to signify the importance of certain concepts to a person, and met conflicting information online. My default assumption would be to replace the -as ending with -us for a male name, but am unsure if that applies to surnames or already Latin-based nouns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Voluntas* comes from the verb *volo*. Roman verb-derived names are fairly common. For instance, from *valeo* we have *Valens* and *Valentinus*; from *vinco* we have *Victor* and *Victorius*.

From *volo* I would derive *Volens*, *Volentinus*, or *Voluntarius*. Of those three, only *Voluntarius* really seems to derive immediately from the noun form.